# React (typescript) import module from other local library: (module has no exports)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created a local library and before publish it to npm I want to test it from another projet.

So I created my library with the following `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

And my `package.json` contains:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "src",
    "README.md"
  ],
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts"
```

After building the lib and getting a "dist" directory, I import a file from this lib on another projet:

```
import {eventProfiler} from "authguard-hiding-spotted/dist/class/Profiler";
```

The IDE allows the import but when I start my app with this import, I got this error:

```
Attempted import error: 'eventProfiler' is not exported from 'authguard-hiding-spotted/dist/class/Profiler' (imported as 'eventProfiler').
```

But why? On my builded file I got this `export declare class eventProfiler`, so the class is explicitly exported.

Comment: `export declare`,  why the declare?, declare will not export anything.